# Grab All posts from multiple groups id

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to develop something like social network, i have a newsfeed and i would like to display all the posts from specific groups that the user joined, basically

i have 3 tables like so

```
------------------
Users Table
------------------
user_id
user_name
__________________
Groups Table
------------------
group_id
group_name
------------------
Posts Table
------------------
post_id
group_id
user_id
post_post
------------------
```

for example, user1 joined group1 and group3, i want to select all posts from group1 and group3. thats it. thank you

Comment: I don't see where in this schema you can determine *"user1 joined group1 and group3"*. Do you have a `user_group` table that would hold that relationship and its attributes?

Comment: i knew there is something like that is missing, im not good at sql, how do i do this?

Comment: The same way you made the other tables. Create a new table that has  `user_id | group_id | <other attributes for this relationship>` where those other attributes might be `create_date` and `active` or what-have-you. Then when `user1` joins `group3` you write that into the table `INSERT INTO user_group (user_id, group_id, create_date) VALUES (1, 3, '2022-10-03');`

Comment: At that point you can solve your original problem `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM user_group WHERE user_id = 1);`.

Comment: I would then question if you need `user_id` on your `posts` table. Is a user an attribute of a post (perhaps the `created_user_id` or `last_updated_user_id` might make sense?)?

Comment: it actually make alot of sense, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. I pulled the test from the comments down into the answer you opened up. Good luck on your build!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will need a new table (from the comments above):

Create a new table that has columns

```
 user_id | group_id | <other attributes for this relationship>
```

where those other attributes might be create_date and active or what-have-you.

Then when `user1` joins `group3` you write that into the table:

```
INSERT INTO user_group (user_id, group_id, create_date) VALUES (1, 3, '2022-10-03');
```

At that point you can solve your original problem by limiting records in your `posts` table using this new table in a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE group_id IN 
   (SELECT group_id FROM user_group WHERE user_id = 1);
```